# Alexa SMAPI - export skill package - 405 Method not allowed

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

According to the documentation on: **[Create an export request for an existing skill](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-package-api-reference.html#create-export)**

> POST /v1/skills/{skillId}/stages/{stage}/exports

But the docs don't say what the POST request `body` should be, so I've tried not sending a body, and tried sending an empty JSON object. Same results.

I'm using cURL with PHP to send a POST request to the full url:

```
$url = "https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skills/$skillId/stages/$stage/exports";

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: '.$access_token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, 'CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION_NONE');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,json_encode(array()));

//enable and get headers, this API response has no body, only headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I receive this error response status:

> HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

---

I know that the `skillId` and `stage` variables are correct because I am able to send POST requests to the other API methods in a similar way without error. (ei. [Update Skill Manifest](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/skill-operations.html#update-a-skill))

I have tried double checking all of the permissions set through Amazon Login, and I am using all of the ones shown in the docs:

```
alexa::ask:skills:read alexa::ask:skills:readwrite alexa::ask:models:read alexa::ask:models:readwrite alexa::ask:skills:test
```

---

**Why is it still returning a 405 error?**

Comment: Using `CURLOPT_NOBODY` changes the request method to `HEAD` rather than `POST`, so try removing that line.

Comment: @ChrisWhite Yes! That was it, it then complained about receiving the start of a list where it wasn't expected so I also needed to remove the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` with the empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CURLOPT_NOBODY changes the request method to HEAD rather than POST, so try removing that line.